# Rails- Building dynamic query for filtering search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I am trying to build a dynamic querying method to filter search results.

My models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_state, -> (state) { joins(:states).where("states.id = ?", state) }
  scope :by_counsel, -> (counsel) { where("counsel_id = ?", counsel) }
  scope :by_sales_rep, -> (sales) { where("sales_id = ?", sales) }
  scope :by_year, -> (year) { where("title_number LIKE ?", "%NYN#{year}%") }
  has_many :properties, :dependent => :destroy 
  has_many :documents, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :participants, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :states, through: :properties
  belongs_to :action
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :type
  belongs_to :sales, :class_name => 'Member'
  belongs_to :counsel, :class_name => 'Member'
  belongs_to :deal_name
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :state
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :properties
    has_many :orders, through: :properties
end
```

I have a page where I display ALL orders by default. I want to have check boxes to allow for filtering of the results. The filters are: Year, State, Sales, and Counsel. an example of a query is: All orders in 2016, 2015("order.title_number LIKE ?", "%NYN#{year}%") in states (has_many through) NJ, PA, CA, etc with sales_id unlimited ids and counsel_id unlimited counsel_ids.

In a nut shell I am trying to figure out how to create ONE query that takes into account ALL options the user checks. Here is my current query code:

```
  def Order.query(opt = {})
    results = []
    orders = []

    if !opt["state"].empty?
      opt["state"].each do |value|
        if orders.empty? 
          orders = Order.send("by_state", value)  
        else
          orders << Order.send("by_state", value)
        end
      end
      orders = orders.flatten
    end

    if !opt["year"].empty?
      new_orders = []

      opt["year"].each do |y| 
        new_orders = orders.by_year(y)
        results << new_orders
      end
    end

    if !opt["sales_id"].empty?

    end

    if !opt["counsel_id"].empty?

    end
    if !results.empty?
      results.flatten 
    else
      orders.flatten
    end
  end
```

Here is the solution I have come up with to allow for unlimited amount of filtering.

```
 def self.query(opts = {})

    orders = Order.all
    opts.delete_if { |key, value| value.blank? }
    const_query = ""
    state_query = nil
    counsel_query = nil
    sales_query = nil
    year_query = nil
    queries = []

    if opts["by_year"]  
      year_query = opts["by_year"].map do |val|
        " title_number LIKE '%NYN#{val}%' "
      end.join(" or ") 
      queries << year_query
    end     

    if opts["by_sales_rep"]
      sales_query = opts["by_sales_rep"].map do |val|
        " sales_id = '#{val}' "
      end.join(" or ")
      queries << sales_query
    end

    if opts["by_counsel"]
      counsel_query = opts["by_counsel"].map do |val|
        " counsel_id = '#{val}' "
      end.join(" or ")
      queries << counsel_query
    end

    if opts["by_state"]      
      state_query = opts["by_state"].map do |val|
        "states.id = '#{val}'"
      end.join(" or ")
    end

    query_string = queries.join(" AND ")

    if state_query
      @orders = Order.joins(:states).where("#{state_query}")
      @orders = @orders.where(query_string)
    else
      @orders = orders.where("#{query_string}")
    end

    @orders.order("title_number DESC")
  end
```

Comment: Do you mean you need one method that calls all those queries? Because in your code you call by_state, which is one, then I assume year is another one etc and so on . so it's not one query . In that case (if it's 4 queries) I don't really see what's the problem...

Comment: Yes I want to call everything with ONE query. Currently I am trying to call the queries individually based on the arguments passed into the query method. Example of the argument is {"year"=>["16", "15"], "state"=>["31", "39"]}. My issue I think is the ability to call  _by_year multiple times with the _by_state conditions. But I do not know how many years, states will be sent. I hope that makes sense @Joel_Blum

Comment: Why not try naming the opt_keys in accordance with the `scopes` e.g. `{by_state: ["31","39"],by_year: "16"}` then you can generically use something like `opts.inject(Order) {|order,(scope,value)| order.public_send(scope,value)}`. This will build an ActiveRecord::Relation with all the filters specified. Then when you act on it the query will actually fire. BTW You will need to fix the `by_year` scope if you wish to pass multiple years.

Comment: You could use a scope method that accepts optional params in recent ruby versions (> 1.9). What ruby are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for a query/filter object, which is a common pattern. I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176005/managing-multiple-get-parameters-in-rails-5-api/39176513#39176513) similar to this, but I'll try to extract the important parts.

First you should move those logic to it's own object. When the search/filter object is initialized it should start with a relation query (`Order.all` or some base query) and then filter that as you go.

Here is a super basic example that isn't fleshed out but should get you on the right track. You would call it like so, `orders = OrderQuery.call(params)`.

```
# /app/services/order_query.rb
class OrderQuery
  def call(opts)
    new(opts).results
  end

  private

  attr_reader :opts, :orders

  def new(opts={})
    @opts = opts
    @orders = Order.all  # If using Rails 3 you'll need to use something like
                         # Order.where(1=1) to get a Relation instead of an Array.
  end

  def results
    if !opt['state'].empty?
      opt['state'].each do |state|
        @orders = orders.by_state(state)
      end
    end

    if !opt['year'].empty?
      opt['year'].each do |year| 
        @orders = orders.by_year(year)
      end
    end

    # ... all filtering logic
    # you could also put this in private functions for each
    # type of filter you support.

    orders
  end
end
```

EDIT: Using OR logic instead of AND logic

```
# /app/services/order_query.rb
class OrderQuery
  def call(opts)
    new(opts).results
  end

  private

  attr_reader :opts, :orders

  def new(opts={})
    @opts = opts
    @orders = Order.all  # If using Rails 3 you'll need to use something like
                         # Order.where(1=1) to get a Relation instead of an Array.
  end

  def results
    if !opt['state'].empty?
      @orders = orders.where(state: opt['state'])
    end

    if !opt['year'].empty?
      @orders = orders.where(year: opt['year'])
    end

    # ... all filtering logic
    # you could also put this in private functions for each
    # type of filter you support.

    orders
  end
end
```

The above syntax basically filters sayings `if state is in this array of states` and `year is within this array of years`.

Comment: Thanks !, I follow the logic and have started to implement this. My main concern now is what if I want multiple filters applied at the same time. Example is, 4x states and 3 years. How can I go through @orders and specifically say, I need these 3 years worth of orders within these 4 states? I currently see your solution working with just one selection for each category. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting OR logic instead of AND logic. The above code iteratively filters down using AND type syntax. If you want it to be OR logic, (ie, orders with year 2015 OR 2016), you'll need to slightly modify the logic. Code updated above.

Comment: I am looking for both AND and OR logic. AND logic for the different filtering options (state, year, etc.) the OR logic for when there are multiples of the filtering options. Example. All orders from 2016, 2015 by salesman 1,2,3  in the states NY, NJ, PA, MA.

Comment: Well I've given you both types of filtering logic. Is there still a question not being answered?

Comment: Hello! I have come up with a solution based on some of your recommendations. See updated code in question.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the filter options came from the Controller's params, so I've done something like this:

The `ActionController::Parameters` structure:

```
{
  all: <Can be true or false>,
  has_planned_tasks: <Can be true or false>
  ... future filters params
}
```

The filter method:

```rb
  def self.filter(filter_params)
    filter_params.reduce(all) do |queries, filter_pair|
      filter_key = filter_pair[0]
      filter_value = filter_pair[1]

      return {
        all: proc { queries.where(deleted_at: nil) if filter_value == false },
        has_planned_tasks: proc { queries.joins(:planned_tasks).distinct if filter_value == true },
      }.fetch(filter_key).call || queries
    end
  end
```

Then I call the `ModelName.filter(filter_params.to_h)` in the Controller. I was able to add more conditional filters easily doing like this.

There's space for improving here, like extract the filters logic or the whole filter object, but I let you decide what is better in your context.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I built for an ecommerce order dashboard in Rails with the parameters coming from the controller.

This query will execute twice, once to count the orders and once to return the requested orders according to the parameters in the request.

This query supports:

- Sort by column
- Sort direction
- Incremental Search - It'll search the beginning of a given field and returns those records that match enabling real-time suggestions while searching
- Pagination (limited by 100 records per page)

I also have predefined values to sanitize some of the data.

This style is extremely clean and easy for others to read and modify.

Here's a sample query:

```
api/shipping/orders?pageNumber=1&orderStatus=unprocessedOrders&filters=standard,second_day&stores=82891&sort_column=Date&sort_direction=dsc&search_query=916
```

And here's the controller code:

```
user_id = session_user.id
order_status = params[:orderStatus]

status = {
  "unprocessedOrders" => ["0", "1", "4", "5"],
  "processedOrders" => ["2", "3", "6"],
  "printedOrders" => ["3"],
  "ratedOrders" => ["1"],
}

services = [
  "standard",
  "expedited",
  "next_day",
  "second_day"
]

countries = [
  "domestic",
  "international"
]

country_defs = {
  domestic: ['US'],
  international: ['CA', 'AE', 'EU', 'GB', 'MX', 'FR']
}

columns = {
  Number: "order_number",
  QTY: "order_qty",
  Weight: "weight",
  Status: "order_status",
  Date: "order_date",
  Carrier: "ship_with_carrier",
  Service: "ship_with_carrier_code",
  Shipping: "requestedShippingService",
  Rate: "cheapest_rate",
  Domestic: "country",
  Batch: "print_batch_id",
  Skus: "skus"
}
# sort_column=${sortColumn}&sort_direction=${sortDirection}&search_query=${searchQuery}

filters = params[:filters].split(',')
stores = params[:stores].split(',')
sort_column = params[:sort_column]
sort_direction = params[:sort_direction]
search_query = params[:search_query]
sort_by_column = columns[params[:sort_column].to_sym]
sort_direction = params[:sort_direction] == "asc" ? "asc" : "desc"

service_params = filters.select{ |p| services.include?(p) }
country_params = filters.select{ |p| countries.include?(p) }
order_status_params = filters.select{ |p| status[p] != nil }

query_countries = []

query_countries << country_defs[:"#{country_params[0]}"]  if country_params[0]
query_countries << country_defs[:"#{country_params[1]}"] if country_params[1]

active_filters = [service_params, country_params].flatten

query = Order.where(user_id: user_id)
query = query.where(order_status: status[order_status]) if order_status_params.empty?
query = query.where("order_number ILIKE ? OR order_id::TEXT ILIKE ? OR order_info->'advancedOptions'->>'customField2' ILIKE ?", "%#{search_query}%", "%#{search_query}%", "%#{search_query}%") unless search_query.gsub(/\s+/, "").length == 0
query = query.where(requestedShippingService: service_params) unless service_params.empty?
query = query.where(country: "US") if country_params.include?("domestic") && !country_params.include?("international")
query = query.where.not(country: "US") if country_params.include?("international") && !country_params.include?("domestic")
query = query.where(order_status: status[order_status_params[0]]) unless order_status_params.empty?
query = query.where(store_id: stores) unless stores.empty?\

order_count = query.count
num_of_pages =  (order_count.to_f / 100).ceil()
requested_page = params[:pageNumber].to_i

formatted_number = (requested_page.to_s + "00").to_i

query = query.offset(formatted_number - 100) unless requested_page == 1
query = query.limit(100)
query = query.order("#{sort_by_column}": :"#{sort_direction}") unless sort_by_column == "skus"
query = query.order("skus[1] #{sort_direction}") if sort_by_column == "skus"
query = query.order(order_number: :"#{sort_direction}")
orders = query.all

puts "After querying orders mem:" + mem.mb.to_s

requested_page = requested_page <= num_of_pages ? requested_page : 1
options = {}
options[:meta] = {
  page_number: requested_page,
  pages: num_of_pages,
  type: order_status,
  count: order_count,
  active_filters: active_filters
}

render json: OrderSerializer.new(orders, options).serialized_json
```